# How to auto redirect after X seconds in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

What is the right way to do this in AngularJS? I didn't find any simple answer to this.

I'd like to :

1. Load a page
2. Wait for X seconds
3. Being automatically redirected to another page after these seconds.

Note: I'm using ui-routing (states) to perform redirections

Thanks.

Comment: Use `timeout` and use `$state.go` to the specific state

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works (thanks PSL):

```
.controller('SeeYouSoonCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$timeout',
                                function($scope, $state, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function() {
      $state.go('AnotherState');
      }, 3000);

    }])
```

Answer (score 3):

It does work also using `$location` instead of `$state`!

### JS

```
app.controller('SeeYouSoonCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function() {
      $location.path('/nextsite');
      }, 3000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Their are two way `$location` and `$timeout`. This will solve your issue:

> 1. By `$timeout` method :

code :

```
  .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$state', '$timeout',
                                function($scope, $state, $timeout) {    
   $timeout(function() {
      $state.go('anotherstate');
      }, 4000);

    }])
```

> 2. By `$location` method :

code:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$state', '$location',
                                    function($scope, $state, $location) {    
      $location.path('/appurl');

        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply redirect to aby other component by this:

open your filename.component.file and ADD this function

```
$timeout(function() {
      $location.path('/login');
      }, 3000);

});
```

and your page will be redirect to login component after 3 second

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the same feature in angular 2 +.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    // do init at here for current route.

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['nextRoute']);
    }, 5000);  //5s
}
```