# Redirect after X seconds AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368394/how-to-auto-redirect-after-x-seconds-in-angularjs) but it uses `ui-router` and I'm only using the `$routeProvider` of AngularJS. The code in the thread is:

```
.controller('SeeYouSoonCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$timeout',
    function($scope, $state, $timeout) {

        $timeout(function() {
            $state.go('AnotherState');
        }, 3000);

    }])
```

How can I use it with my `routeProvider` since I am not using `ui-router`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

```
$location.path('/anotherURL');
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: :) glad to help you cheerz :)

Answer (score 0):

By `$location` method :

code:

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$state', '$location',
                                    function($scope, $state, $location) {    
      $location.path('/appurl');

        }])
```