# Auto redirecting after n seconds using Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wanted to display a page for 'n' seconds and then redirect to another route.

Came across a couple of stackoverflow posts ([url1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368394/how-to-auto-redirect-after-x-seconds-in-angularjs) and [url2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075122/redirect-after-x-seconds-angularjs)) about auto redirecting after 'n' seconds in Angular 1.x. But I m confused how to implement the same in Angular2?

Comment: `window.setTimeout` and then redirect as you normally would in angular2. If you want more help please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can inject and use `Router` from `@angular/router` and navigate in `setTimeout`.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    // do init at here for current route.

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['nextRoute']);
    }, 5000);  //5s
}
```

Comment: just to make it clear the router object should be injected inside the constructor

Answer (score 1):

its a-bit sketchy but this will work.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
          });
        }, 3400);
      }
```

Comment: Seems this is similar to the above accepted answer.. i.e. to use setTimeout. You don't need 2 setTimeout as well.