# Navigate one page to another page automatically in Angular4

Tags: angular, navigation

I am developing online game in Angular 4 framework.

Once Preload complete the page should redirect to my game page. But I don't know how can I **redirect automatically in Angular 4**. Can you please anyone explain with example it will better for me.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean by automatically?

Comment: On your initial page load event call a function which navigate to the desired page

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488068/auto-redirecting-after-n-seconds-using-angular-2

Comment: @AmiLinn in my opinion using setTime doesn't make any sense and we should not use it. In general waiting simply for 5 second doesn't make sense if server sends response in 15 seconds

Comment: then redirect after getting the response. Please show us the code to explain.

Comment: Do you have an api call there?

Answer (score 0):

use Router.navigate() and navigate to different page when preload is done

```
export class Preloader {
      constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.preloadItems();
      }

      preloadItems() {
       // once preload done
       this.router.navigate(['/your_route_path']);
      }
    }
```

Comment: your code will not wait untill the previous loading is done. It will navigate to next route once the class is created

Comment: what do you mean by previous loading? He has to do the routing once pre load completes using router.navigate, offcourse you can wait inside preLoadItems method

Answer (score 0):

As per My understanding if you want to redirect your page after complete load of page than you can use `ngAfterViewInit` method, like this :

```
// Import AfterViewInit    
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    // YOUR CODE
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
    };

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._router.navigate(['Your_router_link']);
    }
}
```